# Надо создать .json файл имея название файла

Tags: python, json, tkinter

Так. Вот фрагмент кода на котором собственно говоря и ошибка:

```
def onClick():
        global file_name
        file_name = name.get() + ".json"
        print(file_name)
        with open(str(file_name)) as f:
            f.close
        for record in tree.get_children():
            tree.delete(record)
        txtBox.destroy()
```

Вот ошибка которая выскакивает:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\5kara\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pyProjects\bills\bills.py", line 55, in onClick
    with open(str(file_name)) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'redede.json'
```

P.A Если что "redede" это я так называл файл. ну просто рандомно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь открыть файл, а не создать его. Собственно поэтому ошибка и говорит Вам, что такого файла не существует в данной директории.

**Вам следует прописать что-то подобное:**

```python
import json

def onClick():
    global file_name
    file_name = name.get() + ".json"
    print(file_name)
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        json.dump({}, f)  # Записываем пустой объект JSON для примера, у Вас может быть другое наполнение
        f.close()
    for record in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(record)
    txtBox.destroy()
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Comment: Успехов в Ваших проектах :)

Comment: спасибо, вам тоже.